# python - count occurrences above in lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with the columns X . I would like to create a new column Y out of X

Y should be 1 if X in the same row is 1 and the 0´s (also in X) above should be minimum a count of n (variable). If the zeros above less than n, the result should be "" Y. 
I tried (hours)  np.where, without success. I think I need a lambda-function, but have no idea how to start or research.

Exampel n = 4:

On date 2018-01-25, result is 1 because X is 1 and the 0´s above are more than 4.

On Date 2018-01-25, result is "" because 0´s above just 3 (not 4)

```
 Dates        X    Y (like it should be...)
2018-01-02    0
2018-01-03    0
2018-01-04    0
2018-01-05    0
2018-01-08    0
2018-01-09    0
2018-01-10    0
2018-01-11    0
2018-01-12    0
2018-01-15    0
2018-01-16    0
2018-01-17    0
2018-01-18    0
2018-01-19    0
2018-01-22    0
2018-01-23    0
2018-01-24    0
2018-01-25    1  1
2018-01-29    0  
2018-01-30    0  
2018-01-31    0  
2018-02-02    1  
2018-02-05    0  
2018-02-06    0
2018-02-07    0
2018-02-08    0
2018-02-09    1  1
2018-02-12    1
2018-02-13    0
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output, so I assume that if `Signal_F` is 1 you want to add a new column where `Signal_X = 1` but only if the four rows above are `0`? so IIUC, `2018-02-01` will have `1` in `Signal_X` ?

Comment: no i expect 0 for 2018-02-02, because there are just three 0's above not 4. i tried to post the expecet column. but i changed the names of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `groupby` a temporary column and then do apply a conditional `cumsum` + `cumcount` for some conditional matching.

```
s = (df.assign(var1='x').groupby('var1')['X']
            .apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).ne(0).cumsum()))
# create a temp variable.

df['Count']=df.groupby([df.X,s]).cumcount()+1 # add a Count column.

matches = df.iloc[df.loc[(df['X'] == 1)].index - 1].loc[df['Count'] >= 4].index 
# find the index matches and check if the previous row has +4 or more matches

df.loc[matches + 1,'Y'] = 1 # Create your Y column.

df.drop('Count',axis=1,inplace=True) # Drop the Count Column. 

print(df[df['Y'] == 1]) # print df
    Dates  X    Y
17  2018-01-25  1  1.0
26  2018-02-09  1  1.0
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your solution and time. i tried the code but i got: NullFrequencyError: Cannot shift with no freq

Comment: then you have nulls in your dataframe that you need to handle before you can use the code.